# playwright with typescript failing to build

Tags: typescript, build, playwright

I ran `npm init playwright@latest`, provided `src/tests` as the test directory, and `typescript` as the language. I did not change anything on `playwright.config.ts`.

Next, I created the `src/tests/e2e.spec.ts` file:

```
import { AnalyzePageResponse } from '../messages';
import { AnalyzePageMessage } from '../worker/messages';
import { test, expect } from './fixtures';

test.describe('getElements()', () => {
  test('should work on pages that contain iframes with different origin', async ({ page, worker }) => {
    await page.goto('https://talented-enshrined-pleasure.glitch.me/');
    await worker.evaluate(async () => {
      const tab = (await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }))[0];
      const message = new AnalyzePageMessage(tab.id!);
      const response: AnalyzePageResponse = await chrome.runtime.sendMessage(message);
      expect(response.page.length).toBe(2);
    });
  });
});
```

VsCode is happy with this and does not complain.

However, when I try to run `npx playwright test`, it complains that it cannot find the imported libraries.

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\xxxxxxx\chrome-extension-test\src\worker\messages'

   at e2e.spec.ts:2

  1 | import { AnalyzePageResponse } from '../messages';
> 2 | import { AnalyzePageMessage } from '../worker/messages';
    | ^
  3 | import { test, expect } from './fixtures';
  4 |
  5 | test.describe('getElements()', () => {

    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\xxxxxxx\chrome-extension-test\src\tests\e2e.spec.ts:2:1)

Error: No tests found
```

What's going on here? Any insights?

Here's the folder structure:

```
ª   package.json
ª   playwright.config.ts
ª   tsconfig.json
ª   webpack.config.js
ª   
+---src
    ª   messages.ts
    ª   
    +---tests
    ª       e2e.spec.ts
    ª       fixtures.ts
    ª       
    +---worker
        ª   messages.ts
        ª
```

**UPDATE**

If I add `.ts` to the path `import { AnalyzePageResponse } from '../messages.ts';`, playwright does not complain. However, if the `../messages.ts` file uses other imports, all need to have `.ts`. But I cannot change this and I don't understand what's going on.

**UPDATE 2**

The `tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
       "strict": true,
       "module": "commonjs",
       "target": "es6",
       "esModuleInterop": true,
       "sourceMap": true,
       "rootDir": "./src",
       "outDir": "dist/js",
       "noEmitOnError": true,
       "typeRoots": [ "node_modules/@types" ]
    },
    "exclude": ["playwright.config.ts"]
 }
```

Comment: Is the path correct? Please show your directory structure, and which directory context you're running the command from. Thanks.

Comment: I've added the folder structure. BTW, VsCode does not complain about this. Only when building with `npx playwright test`.

Comment: Please add `tsconfig.json` settings you use

Comment: updated with `tsconfig.json`